# Limiting memory consumption. Physical Vs Virtual memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, ram, virtual-memory

Working on a C# application.

The application memory usage in the Task manager keeps on growing if the application is opened for a long duration.

Before I dive deep into chasing memory leaks and optimizing memory usages, I want to limit the damage (as this task will take a lot of time).

I implemented the following logic:

if the `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` is Larger than 25% of the system total physical memory size, or if the system remaining available memory is less than 10%, I restart my application.

To get the total system physical memory size I used `new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory` (this is returning 16GB on my laptop which is correct)

However I noticed there's another Memory type which is the Virtual memory `new ComputerInfo().TotalVirtualMemory`. this is returning 2GB.

And research told me that Virtual Memory is an area of memory that an application can use without worrying about affecting other applications.

Which brings me to my question:

Can the Virtual memory be considered reliable in a way that as long as my application didn't surpass it, I'm fine?

Is it logical to modify my logic to check against the Virtual Memory instead of the physical memory? Like if the application virtual memory > system virtual memory I restart the application.

Note: I know this is not the correct approach but until optimize the application and look for memory leaks I want to restart the application whenever it starts behaving as a bad citizen on the system

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's a problem? Have you read how garbage collection works and when/how memory is released back to the OS? It's normal for an application size to grow, but if there's demand for the memory then the garbage collector will be more aggressive. You haven't indicated any specifics on the memory usage growth or if it's causing problems on the system.

Comment: You should run your program on 64bit mode. go to `project properties/build` and disable prefer 32bit

Comment: @itsme86 hello, no I am not sure, there might be no problems, but we are receiving a lot of complaints about high memory usage (from the Task manager) so we were forced to limit it even if it's all data that will get deallocated by the GC. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about how virtual memory works.

> And research told me that Virtual Memory is an area of memory that an application can use without worrying about affecting other applications.

A process exists within a virtual (or logical) address space. Within the virtual address pages, Virtual pages are either (1) are mapped to secondary storage; (2) are mapped to physical page frames; or (3) have no mapping at all (i.e. are invalid).

> Can the Virtual memory be considered reliable in a way that as long as my application didn't surpass it, I'm fine?

You cannot surpass the limits of virtual memory. You're like to hit other limits before you reach the end of virtual memory (e.g., page file space, process quotas, system parameters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a question. When you said "ou cannot surpass the limits of virtual memory" you mean an APP cannot take more than 2GB on my 16GB machine? because `new ComputerInfo().TotalVirtualMemory` gives me 2GB

Comment: Several things can limit you. If you are running a 32-bit OS, you can only access 4GB in theory. You can also have process limits on your system.